# How do remove template change message from the PHP Class template in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

In NetBeans, when I add a new file using the PHP Class template, the new class contains the following comment:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
```

Yet this text doesn't appear anywhere in the template when I follow it's instructions to edit the template. How can I avoid having this comment included in all my new classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove `<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">` from the top of the PHP class template. Don't forget to do this for Interface, File, and Web Page.

The text that you are trying to get rid of is part of the **Default License** so you could just change/remove the text there. The Default License is under the Licenses folder in the Template Manager.

Alternatively you could put a blank text file or license file in `~/.netbeans/7.0/config/Templates/Licenses/` and name the file `license-foo.txt` and then in your project.properties file define a key `project.license` and set it to `foo`. If you did this you would need to define the same key for each project or you would get the unwanted text again.

**Edit:** 
Actually to add a license you can just click the Add... button inside the Template Manager after selecting the Licenses folder.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question and steered me toward finding out about including licenses etc.

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help. NetBeans uses FreeMarker as its template engine so it's pretty powerful. See this blog for more info http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/project_level_license_settings_in